# Simple apache root redirect

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

How do I do a redirect as follows?

- Users coming in on `www.domain.com` or `www.domain.com/` should be sent to `www.domain.com/portal`
- If they come in with any URI attached to the domain (ie `www.domain.com/something`), I would send them there and not to `/portal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Apache?

For version 2.0

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/$  /portal/  [R]
```

I took the rule from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html under the section of Moved DocumentRoot.

Comment: Sorry.  It is version 2.2. Your suggestion works!  I actually did read the manual a few times but I guess I passed over that section not understanding some of the terminology.